# Events: Could you, please, tell me if I understood?

Tags: java, android, event-handling

I started few weeks ago to study Java for developing Android apps natively.

In the past, I tried to use Xamarin and C# for mobile cross-platform development but, after a while, I decided to abandon it and make only Android apps directly in Java.

I noticed a lot of stuff in common between Java and C# but there is a thing that is causing me headaches: the event handling mechanism.

It seems that Java does not manage events natively as C# does (C# has delegates and events and these are special types of delegates) but uses interfaces to reach the goal.

Now, when I create a button in Android with a click event I see something like this:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
   // some stuff here
   }
});
```

If I have understood correctly, `btn.setOnClickListener()` is a method used to observe an object implementing the `onClickListener` interface. In this case we are creating a new instance of View object that implements the interface: `new View.OnClickListener()`.
The `onClick(View view)` method is the one defined in the `OnClickListener` interface so we need to implement it with `some stuff`

What is not clear is the meaning of `(View view)` parameter in the `onClick()` method: when I pass it? It seems that I can implement the `onClick()` method without the necessity of passing it. What is its meaning? 
Probably I misunderstood the way Java events work. I tried a lot on the Net but I was not able to find a clear and plain explaination (without involving gui Swing, AWT and so on elements) on how events mechanism works on Java.

Comment: You're honestly overthinking this. Check this page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener

Comment: `I started few weeks ago to study Java for developing Android apps natively.` But native apps are written In C++, by using the NDK.

Answer (score 2):

`setOnClickListener()` defines the callback invoked when a view (in your case a *Button* but it applies to any *View*) is clicked.

`View.OnClickListener` is an interface with only one method `onClick(View v)`. You don't have to initialize or provide any View object, it is the other way around. When a button is pressed the method `onClick(View v)` will be called and `v` will be the actual button that got clicked.

For example you can get the text of the button when it is clicked.

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      Button button = (Button) view;
      Log.d("@@@@", "You clicked the " + button.getText() + " button");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly from my time doing Android the `(View view)` helps the 'onClick' understand that it needs something from the UI to use. If you try without it you'll get an error or if you try `public void buttonClick(){//do something}` then in the XML add `onClick = 'buttonClick'`. You'll also get an error. Basically having `(View view)` just helps the API understand whats going on with the UI.